# Drupal 7 override another function

Tags: drupal-7, overriding

I want to override some function from module.
How can I do this ?
As I know it is possible to override in template. But I didn't understand how.
For instance I want to overrider function from better exposed filters it is 
`function theme_select_as_checkboxes($vars) {...}` and

```
function bef_checkbox($element, $value, $label, $selected) {..}
```

I try to copy-paste in template and rename functions to `mytheme_bef_checkbox($element, $value, $label, $selected) {..}` - but doesn't take anything

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to find a drupal function with '_alter' at the end of it. Find the proper one for yourself. Check the code better exposed filter module uses and find an alter fuction you can use to alter it.